# process pipeline data in real time in windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am using an executable file (rar.exe) that process every file in a directory and all subdirectories. upon finishing each file it outputs file name and an OK message.
for example if you have 1000 files in a directory and its subdirectories, it will display 1000 messages. each message exactly displayed after corresponding file processed.
I can get files count in that directory using the below code:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "cmd=dir %1 /s /A:-d /b"
set /A fileCounts=0
for /f %%a in ('%cmd%') do SET /A fileCounts+=1
```

I want to show the percent of job. I piped result of executable to batch file and used two below codes:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
SET /A counts=0
:do
set /p _s=
if "%_s%"=="" goto end
set /A counts+=1
echo %counts%: "%_s%"
goto do
:end
endlocal
```

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
SET /A counts=0
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('more') do (
  set /A counts+=1
  echo %counts%: #%%a
)
```

the first one does not work correctly at all. the second one is working but it waits until end of executable job and then starts to output the result. so the second one also is not usable
any advise to get the result of executable file at real time and show job percentage of completion (or even line count at that time ) would be appreciated.

Comment: Just an observation. This line will never be true: `if [_s]==[] goto end`.  You need to use percent symbols to get the value of a variable.  Also do not get in habit of using any other characters besides double quotes for comparing strings. Double quotes protect spaces and special characters. `if "%_s%"=="" goto end`

Comment: Just guessing: Second script does not working because windows pipe is buffered. The script chute whole STDIN into a memory andTHAN start processing on it.

Comment: @Squashman thanks for your comment. it was just a typo. it does not get lines correctly at all.

Comment: @user2956477 exactly the problem is buffering the result. and I dont want it to be that way

Comment: But windows shell scripting generally working this way, have doubts this could be avoided. As I am not a progranmmer, check if rar.exe is able to print unbuffered output.

Answer (score 0):

I could help you if you still need help at this date... But i would need more information about how and what type of output rar.exe do in your case... Hmmm... I assume you call rar.exe from cmd.exe right ? And i assume as well it outputs in the terminal ( command line ).
If its the case and if I assumed right you gotta call rar.exe redirecting directly to a file and then process in parralel the file...
Wich is not easy...
Or you could use tee.exe
From here: https://unxutils.sourceforge.net/
And do such :

```
rar.exe | tee.exe file.txt
```

This would process in real time the output of rar.exe in theory. But at the end i dont even know if it would work.
Scripting in batch is limited you could watch for visual basic, PowerShell. Im gonna try it on my side i have a similar project and i will send an update on it.

***Otherwise...***

Indent everything to the right that is inside... 4 spaces or 2 basic tabs. (Tab can be modified to do more spaces)

```
SETLOCAL setdelayedexpansion 
    @REM ( The code ) 
ENDLOCAL
```

try to help yourself visualize your code the fastest way the most efficient way... Standardized way... You know what i mean. I recommend anyone who do any sort of programming or scripting to do it in VS Code (Visual Studio Code) its in my opinion the globally best one for just a text editor i mean. It's free...
I also encourage you to test every single line of your scripts when you have problems especially closely cause there's no debugger of course... Lol. So what i do is, i put

```
@echo on 
Pause
```

And move it line per line and each time run the script until it it doesn't show up on screen ( for 1/2 sec!!).
Its the kind of operation that is really easy you select these lines and do alt+down arrow key ( in vs code)
And run the script... Again and again to debug any script if you aren't able to tell what's the problem right now.
Or just on one line

```
@ECHO ON & ECHO DEBUG PAUSE... & PAUSE > nul
```

Its a custom pause...
I mean... As you do it then do it like a pro. Its not an insult its a kindly advice :).

Sorry this is bad cause im writing this from my phone and im lazy.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but ...

Some explanations:

If you pipe into a FOR /F loop, like in

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('more') do (
```

The FOR loop will always wait until the complete data is received by the command (in this case `more`) and the command is finished.
This obviously can't solve your problem.

On the other side, if you pipe to a batch which receives data with the `set /p` command, this works immediately, but `set /p` doesn't work reliable with pipes, it fails when line feeds are in the data, then it removes parts of the data.

But `set /p` works reliable with redirection!
How to build a redirection from a pipe? - Using a temporary file -
But how to redirect, if `set /p` can't receive from a pipe and `FOR/F` waits?
Using `FIND` to receive the data from the pipe and redirect it to a temporary file.
To detect the end of the pipe I added a simple `echo ende`, but to distinguish between the last `ende` and a possible `ende` in the piped data I use `FIND /N`to prefix each line with a line number.

For this you need two batch tasks, one for convert from pipe to temp file and the second to consume the data from the temp file.

pipeReceiver.bat

```
@echo off
REM *** Trampoline jump for function calls of the form ex. "C:\:function:\..\MyBatchFile.bat"
FOR /F "tokens=3 delims=:" %%L in ("%~0") DO goto :%%L

REM The first part read from the input pipe
REM The second part consumes the data from the temp file
REM The pipe here is used only to start tasks
break > async.tmp
rem start /b "" 
(
  echo RECEIVER > CON
  find /n /V ""
  (echo ende)
) > async.tmp | "%~d0\:consumer:\..\%~pnx0"
exit /b

exit /b

:consumer
echo :consumer started
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
< async.tmp call :_consumer
echo :consumer finished
exit /b

:_consumer
set "line="
set /p line=

if not defined line goto :_consumer
if "!line:~0,4!" EQU "ende" exit /b
set "line=!line:*]=!"

(echo('!line!')
goto :_consumer
```

Now you can use something like

```
dir | pipeReceiver.bat
```

or

```
rar ... | pipeReceiver.bat
```